# How can we register a resource file in manifest.xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

I am creating an android application. Till now, it is perfectly executing all the time. But, after creating a resource file, it is shutting down. What can I do now? Do I have to register strings.xml?

Comment: Shutting down how? You do not need to register xml files. Where did you create the strings.xml? It should go under res/values/strings.xml

Comment: If application is crashing then post your log cat. @shiva

Comment: post ur resource file and the way how you access that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys.....actually what I did is, when I was creating strings.xml...I deleted another 2 resource files,i.e,dimen.xml and some other. That's y it was shutting down abnormally. Now, again I added them to values folder and working fine. ThnQ guys.....